# php output hours based on locale

Tags: php

I am working on a project that requires me to list the 24 hours of the day in the locale format.

Here is what I have:

```
$time_fmt = datefmt_create(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::LONG, '', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'H:i');
echo datefmt_format($time_fmt, mktime(1, 0));
```

It seems this should make 01:00 or 1:00am depending on the locale. But, it is outputting '8:'.

How can I use datefmt_create() and dtefmt_format() to list the 24 hours of the day in the locale format?

Answer (score 0):

This works: (tested)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
$times = array(
    '00:00:00',
    '01:00:00',
    '02:00:00',
    '03:00:00',
    '04:00:00',
    '05:00:00',
    '06:00:00',
    '07:00:00',
    '08:00:00',
    '09:00:00',
    '10:00:00',
    '11:00:00',
    '12:00:00',
    '13:00:00',
    '14:00:00',
    '15:00:00',
    '16:00:00',
    '17:00:00',
    '18:00:00',
    '19:00:00',
    '20:00:00',
    '21:00:00',
    '22:00:00',
    '23:00:00'
);

foreach( $times as $time ){
    echo strftime("%X", strtotime($time)) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only deals with the current time. I need the individual hours from 00:00 to 23:00.

Comment: You can pass a manual time into the strftime as a second arg. Edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$time = strtotime('English Date With Time');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles or wherever');
echo date('H:i', $time);
```

If you're just doing the hours, not the date, then just know what timezone you are in. Translate everything to UTC and do some maths modulo 24.